# TCP Client hangs with Perl fork() + system()

Tags: perl, sockets

I have a perl script running a TCP listener via Net::Server module. When the remote connects to the perl server, the remote sends the filename of an mp3 music file to play.  When I fork() and then call system('mpg123 $filename'), the client hangs. How can I background the mpg123 process so the child can close the connection?

```
my $pid = fork();

      if (defined $pid && $pid == 0)
      {
         # child process  -- never gets to print statement until $cmd is done
         system ($cmd);
         print STDERR "child launched\n";
         exit (0);
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using Proc::Daemon

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Proc::Daemon;

my $dm = Proc::Daemon->new( work_dir=>'/tmp/');
my $pid = $dm->Init( { exec_command => '/usr/bin/find / >/tmp/find.txt', } );

while (1)
{
   print "child status :".$dm->Status($pid)."\n";
   sleep 2;
   if ($dm->Status($pid) eq 0)
   {
      print "child terminated :".$dm->Status($pid)."\n";
      last;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl’s `system` doesn’t return until the command completes. You might rearrange the child to

```
if (defined $pid && $pid == 0)
{
    # child process
    warn "child launched\n";
    exec $cmd or die "$0: exec $cmd: $!";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I suspected as much.